# I need Javascript to validate a users button and force input for that buttons text input using javascript

Tags: javascript

When the left button is selected the left input text should be required to enter by the user, If the user selects the left button and clicks submit without entering text the form should throw an error, I should only be using javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<body>
    <form action="\">
               <label for="left">left</label>
               <input type="radio" id="left">
               <label for="right">right</label>
               <input type="radio" id="right"><br>
               
               <label for="left">left</label>
               <input type="text" name="leftInput" id="rightText">
               <label for="right">right</label>
               <input type="text" name="rightInput" id="leftText">
               
               <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="submit">
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with just HTML

Try adding a 'required' attribute to the input as such:

```
<input type="text" name="leftInput" id="rightText" required>
```